# How can I show the python console on my GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, user-interface, console, desktop-application

Im new at programming and I want to show the Python console in a square in my GUI, how can I do that, I just want to show the console in the GUI

Comment: So you want to show command prompt inside the ```tkinter``` window

Comment: what kind of gui library are you using?

Comment: Im using Tkinter

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
import tkinter as tk

cmd = os.popen("your console command").read()

r = tk.Tk()
tk.Label(r,text = cmd).grid(row=0,column=0)
r.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: What should I put in "your command" if I want to print all the python console?